# Putting char values into a 2D array from a file in Java

Tags: java, arrays, file, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have a file with a known number of 40,000 digits.
I need to read the digits one by one so I've created a for loop where I read the file in chars.
The file is made up of numbers from 0 to 9.
I need to filter out numbers 0 to 3 and 4 to 9.
Numbers 0 to 3 need to be replaced with the letter x
Numbers 4 to 9 need to be replaced with the letter y
How do I go about storing these digits within the 2D array?
The array is [200][200] as this is the size of the window in which the x's and y's will be printed.

```
char[][] myArray = new char [200][200];

    for (int i=0; i<=39000; i++) {
    char readFile = fileInput.readChar();
    {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char[][] myArray = new char [200][200];

    for (int i=0; i<200; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<200; j++) {
            char readFile = fileInput.readChar();
            if (readFile < '4')
                myArray [i][j] = 'x';
            else
                myArray [i][j] = 'y';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Instead of x and y, i need them to be dots of colour on a graphics screen. Any idea how to go about this..?

Comment: The OP said *the window in which the x's and y's will be printed*. You've now changed your question dramatically. I was happy to modify your posted code attempt, but I can't supply a solution to your new problem, which is radically different. You have to attempt that yourself.

Comment: But thanks, I've done it all now you were very helpful!